# Translate Delegates from c# to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview, treelistview

I am using the TreeListView control from BrightIdeas software.  Looks great but I'm not familiar with delegates, and the example is in c#.  Can someone lend me a hand translating this to VB.NET?

This is the example:

```
    this.treeListView.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x) {
        Return ((MyFileSystemInfo) x).IsDirectory;
    };
```

And this is my best guess as to the intent (obviously wrong)

```
    Dim expander As TreeListView.CanExpandGetterDelegate
    expander = AddressOf IsReportPopulated
    '// CanExpandGetter Is called very often! It must be very fast.
    Me.treeListView.CanExpandGetter = expander(x As Object) ' no idea where we are getting the object from
```

And the function is defined as this

```
Private Function IsReportPopulated(x As Object) As Boolean
    Dim myreport As ADCLReport = CType(x, ADCLReport)
    If myreport.Chambers.Count > 0 Or myreport.Electrometers.Count > 0 Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

Per advice, ran through a translator.  Doesn't look quite right.  Output:

```
thisPublic Delegate Sub ((ByVal Unknown As x)
{Return(CType(x,MyFileSystemInfo)).IsDirectory
UnknownUnknown
```

Comment: Did you try running this through a translator first?

Comment: Translators aren't anywhere near 100 percent accurate, but I'd agree that's a good starting point.

Comment: See revisions, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# code is the way you had to attempt to write a lambda before C# had lambdas - it's usually written as:

```
this.treeListView.CanExpandGetter = (object x) =>
{
    return ((MyFileSystemInfo)x).IsDirectory;
};
```

The VB equivalent is:

```
Me.treeListView.CanExpandGetter = Function(x As Object)
    Return DirectCast(x, MyFileSystemInfo).IsDirectory
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes a lot of sense now.